# Recommendation for ADSL modem/router that supports multiple servers w. static IPs?

Tags: router, modem, adsl

I have what doesn't seem like all that complicated a network in my home: I have a block of 8 (= 5 usable) static IP addresses, which are assigned to five externally-visible servers; I also have a bunch of Macs and PCs and other connected devices that get their IP addresses via NAT.  I'm currently using a Netopia 3346-ENT, but its time has kinda passed, and am looking for a new modem/router.  I've been considering the Netgear DGN3500, but, after looking its manual, I can't figure out how to set up the external address - internal address mappings, or if the router will even let me do this (I've had one guy on another board say that it can't, and that I have to to go some unspecified Netgear ProSafe product).

Any advice out there?  I understand that I may need something more heavy-duty than a basic home modem/router, but finding the next step up can't be THAT hard...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you look at running [pfSense](http://pfsense.org/) on an [ALIX](http://store.netgate.com/ALIX2D3-2D13-Kit-Unassembled-P1030.aspx) embedded device. That will be *far* more flexible and stable than your current solution. For connecting to your ADSL modem, usually you can put the modem into transparent bridging mode, then plug the WAN port of your pfSense router into the modem and have the router do the PPPoE authentication/negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Cisco 1811 to do just that. Like always with (pro) Cisco stuff it's not really easy to get the configuration right, but once it's done it works like a charm. I found the (java) GUI pretty useless, so you have to to it directly in Cisco OS CLI if you want anything beyond the basics.

It has four network ports that can be assigned to a seperate VLAN each. Each VLAN can have its own (public) IP address that either does NAT for a pool of desktops or goes straight to a server without NAT.

I use it to completely seperate two companies with their own LAN and to give direct public access to two servers.

It's not really cheap, though. I couldn't find any prosumer device that could do this. I contacted several companies to figure this out.

Comment: pfSense running on, well anything from an embedded computer to an old PC sitting in the closet will do this very easily.